# Angular 2 with Polymer failed ng serve

Tags: angular, polymer, command-line-interface

after I configured my application I have this error at start:
"Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options."
I could not find one good solution for solving this. From what I understood it s seems to be a problem with  a new file I made module-polymer.ts, somehow fails to parse the bootstrap.

Any solution guys?

I desperately need help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it. It seems to be a problem with the new versions of angular cli. I changed the cli and now I have no problem. right now I downgraded  to angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3

Answer (score 0):

Check your ng version "ng -v"
It should look something like this:

angular-cli:1.0.0-beta.(your version)

node: version

os: newer mind

Than open package.json and shed your devDependencies angular-cli version.
Is there a difference?
Set version from ng -v command.

And last.
Delete node_modules, than set command "npm i", and after it "ng serve".

Work?

Comment: the verision of node was 1.0.0-beta.22.something - I made a downgrade at 19.3 witch seems to work fine.